# translate trail_offset and trail_points, Pine Script to Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pine-script

I would like to convert the "strategy.exit" line of my Pine Script code. Please don't pay attention to the "loss" part, but focus on "trail_points" and "trail_offset". In Python, I can't seem to understand how "trail_points" and "trail_offset" are defined, so I need help creating an equivalent. Can you assist me in creating this in Python and achieving similar selling calculations as my TradingView strategy?

code pine script

```
tp_pct = input.float(1, title="Trailing Threshold (%)", group="Trailing Stop")
to_pct = input.float(0.5, step=0.5, title="Trailing Offset (%)", group="Trailing Stop")

tp_ticks = close * tp_pct / 100
to_ticks = close * to_pct / 100

strategy.exit(' Stop Exit', 'Long', loss=sl_price, trail_points=tp_ticks, trail_offset=to_ticks, comment_loss='Stop Loss', comment_trailing='Trail Profit')
```

I have already tried various calculations and numerous queries against the AI, but none of the responses have been conclusive.